# What does "I don’t even count them in the till" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I don’t even count them in the till.

What is the meaning of "**in the till**" here? I googled but got nothing for this.

Comment: I second Theta30(below). Its a noun for a cash-drawer. Check http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/04/till.html for more.

Comment: sunleo, what is the context for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **till** = a cash register or drawer for money in a shop, bank, or restaurant:
>    *there were queues at the till checkout tills*

[Source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/till--2)

So the sentence refers to counting money in the till.

Comment: It is a machine for working out and handling payments in a business, which includes a drawer. You can see at the following link that this word is used in British English and is called a "cash register" in American English http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/till_2